# Python Parallel Scraping + Dump to JSON

Tags: python, json, multiprocessing

Looking for opinions on the following skeleton code. I will be using a large input list for some web scraping and would like to parallelize the function along with writing the output to a json file in chunks in case the process fails I don't lose the work. The code produces the output I want, function f will be the scraper and the print(results) will be the output to the json file. Wondering if there is a more efficient method:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

def f(x):
    print('Doing: ' + str(x) + ' with process id:'+ str(os.getpid()) + '\n')
    return(x*x)

def main():
    id_list = range(1000)
    chunksize = 10

    lock = mp.Lock()

    for i in range(0, len(id_list), chunksize):
        chunk = id_list[i : i + chunksize]

        p = mp.Pool(12)
        results = p.map(f, chunk)

        for j in range(len(results)):
            lock.acquire()
            try:
                print('The results is: ' + str(results[j]) + '\n')
            finally:
                lock.release()
        p.close()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print("Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

Each process could write their own output into a separate file, and you can deal with combining them later.

That way you don't have to deal with locks or possible writing concurrency issues or whatever in this code at all.